# how to set up shared memory and make it available?

Tags: linux, memory, sybase

I try to setup shared memory for Sybase ASE 12.5 on CentOS. My server has 17G memory, I want to make 14G (=17-1-2)available for sybase. (1G for os, 2G for ramdisk 14 = 17-1-2).

here is the info:

```
[sybase@myserver ASE-12_5]$ free -g
total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 17 7 9 0 0 7
-/+ buffers/cache: 0 17
Swap: 3 0 3
```

There are 2G ramdisk setup.

```
[sybase@myserver ASE-12_5]$ df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2 12G 2.6G 8.8G 23% /
/dev/sda1 251M 19M 220M 8% /boot
none 8.7G 0 8.7G 0% /dev/shm ---what's this? is it related kernel.shmmax?
/dev/sdb1 30G 8.4G 20G 30% /home
tmpfs 2.1G 20M 2.1G 1% /db/tempdb -----this is ramdisk, what 's the difference between this and /dev/shm???
```

then I modify /ect/sysctl.conf as:

```
[sybase@myserver ASE-12_5]$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled. See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.
# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 1
# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
# kernel.shmmax = 10737418240
kernel.shmmax= 14738890752 ------modify this to 13.7G
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.shmall = 2097152
```

then run:

```
echo "kernel.shmmax=14738890752" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

then reboot CentOS.

then I try to set sybase max memory to 7196724(2K), but I can's start sybase and got error:

```
00:00000:00000:2014/04/02 16:50:26.92 kernel os_create_region: shmget(0xf402f74d): No space left on device
00:00000:00000:2014/04/02 16:50:26.92 kernel kbcreate: couldn't create kernel region.
00:00000:00000:2014/04/02 16:50:26.92 kernel kistartup: could not create shared memory
```

It's only allow me to set max memory as 40000009(2k)=7.6G

Not sure why. So setup shared memory on CentOS, only change kernel.shmmax in /etc/sysctl.conf is not enough? Or need to do more?

Also, I don't under 2 rows in output of `df -h`:

```
none 8.7G 0 8.7G 0% /dev/shm ---what's this? is it related kernel.shmmax
tmpfs 2.1G 20M 2.1G 1% /db/tempdb -----this is ramdisk
```

how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to allocate larger segments than permitted by `shmmax` results in `EINVAL (Invalid argument)`, that's not what you are getting. Trying to allocate more than the committed memory limit results in `ENOSPC (No space left on device)` which is what you are getting.

As far as I recall the limit defaults to half the physical RAM plus total swap space. You can see your current value with this command `grep CommitLimit /proc/meminfo`

The size of the `tmpfs` file systems are controlled by the `size` mount option as explained in `man mount`.

The `/dev/shm` file system is used by the `shm_open` call. That is unrelated to `shmget` those are two different APIs originating from Posix and SysV.